# CI Temporary Schema Not Deleting

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I've recently enabled the CI feature on dbt Cloud. Their documentation mentions that

> Once the PR is closed, dbt Cloud will delete the temporary schema.

But it seems like these schemas aren't actually deleting once I've closed the PR.

Anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Does your dbt executing user on snowflake (Example snowflake_dbt) have all permissions for all schemas on that DB?

I'd start by checking something like the following and then check for what privileges are enabled for *all schemas* on that database:

`SHOW GRANTS TO USER <dbt_user>`

`SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE <dbt_service_role>`

`SHOW GRANTS ON SCHEMA <ci_schema>`

`SHOW GRANTS ON DATABASE <ci_database>`

Reminder, dbt is creating the schema on the fly so pre-existing schema privileges won't apply. This is a privilege that will have to be given to *all schemas* on that database for either that user or role.